What is this mysterious symbol on the clothing of Tunisian Jews?
With the permission of the OP, I'm asking here a question first raised on the Judaism SE.
In some old photos of Tunisian Jews, including some prominent rabbis, some are shown with a mysterious symbol on their clothes. For example, Hakham (=Rabbi) Haim Huri (חכם חיים חורי):

Two men in this group standing with their backs to the famous Djerba El-Ghriba Synagogue:

and in some other examples I've found (here, here, and here).
Previously, I checked Rabbi Huri's Hebrew biography, חיי חיים: חייו ופועלו של רבנו חיים חורי (The Life of Haim: The Life and Acts of our Master Haim Huri), by his grandson Shushan Huri. On p. 67 it said that when he had to meet with governmental officials he would borrow fancy clothes from wealthy neighbors. I don't know whether that information is pertinent. I also contacted the webmaster of tunisia.co.il, a Hebrew site on the history and culture of Tunisian Jews, but he told me that he's never found an explanation for this symbol.
Does anyone know what this symbol represents?

This is the highest rank of the Jedi Rabbis :)

@OldPadawan hehe, nice. :D Didn't think of that.

Extensive research ends up fruitless... It might be something used locally only maybe. Looking at the symbols, we could have the arab crescent, the sikh khaṇḍā, a "one-branch menorah" (?), all mixed into one oecumenical symbol? Just a thought though...

@OldPadawan thanks. Both I and the OP back at the Judaism SE thought it might be the symbol of some kind of fraternity. But of course we have no idea whether there were such things in Tunisia and whether Jews were members of such groups.

well, on hickstory.se, they're definately Jedi Rabbis :D
